# Inline CSS that uses fallthroughs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Before using react, I had this as part of my CSS:

```
.tile {
    image-rendering: pixelated;
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}
```

If I want to inline my CSS in react, I do this:

```
function Tile(props) {
    const style = {
        imageRendering: 'pixelated',
        imageRendering: 'crisp-edges',
    }
    return <Tile style={style} />
}
```

Since `style` has a duplicate key, only one of the rules will get applied, which means the CSS will work in fewer browsers.

Is there any way of preserving the fallthrough behavior of separated CSS in inlined CSS?

Comment: Just a guess, but have you tried using an array? `imageRendering: ['pixelated', 'crisp-edges']`

Comment: @Rob Using an array makes the property not work at all. For now I'm just not inlining it.

Comment: It was purely a guess based on how multiple transforms are defined.

Comment: does the original css even work? What is that even meant to do?

Comment: @A.Lau The original css makes scaled images not use anti-aliasing. I use it to make pixel art look crisp on retina displays.

Comment: Yes, but having both the same properties means that the last one will override the earlier one

Comment: @A.Lau Firefox only supports one, and Chrome the other. They will ignore the unsupported value, so using both makes the css work in both browsers.

Comment: maybe try using browser detection instead?